# Paginating with DataTables using server-side processing

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using ajax to query my database and bring back a json object of data. I want to paginate the data using DataTables. I'm having trouble getting DataTables to recognize my post variable (named "code") and to return any data in table format. Can anyone help?

html:

```
<label for="medProcDataList" class="form-label">Medical Procedures with hospital codes</label>
    
    <select class="form-select" id="medProcDataList">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <!-- this is populated with a different ajax call -->
    </select>
</form>

<table id="results"></table>
```

jquery

```
var $selectedValue = $(this).val();
var arrSelVal = $selectedValue.split(":");
$code = arrSelVal[0]; //get hospital code

$('#results').DataTable( { //returns nothing; does not recognize my code variable
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        data: {code: $code },
        "ajax": "php/getDataForCode.php",
        columns: [
                { title: "Hospital", data: "hospital_name" },
                { title: "Description", data: "raw_description" },
                { title: "Insurer", data: "full_payer_name" },
                { title: "Insurer type", data: "play_type"},
                { title: "You Pay", data: "price" }
        ]
    } );
```

php

```
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit;
}
mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8'); //important! or it won't echo the array

    if( $_POST) {
        $code = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['code']);
        $data = array();
        $q = "SELECT hospital_name, raw_description, full_payer_name, plan_type, format([price], 'N0') FROM `hospital_transparency_data` where procedure_codes = '" . $code . "' order by hospital_name, full_payer_name";
        $result = $db->query($q);
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            //Add this row to the reply
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        
        
        $db->close();
        echo json_encode($data);
    
    } //if POST
```

Am I doing this right? DataTables doesn't recognize my data variable and throws an error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=results - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
```

Comment: Not an answer, just some observations: (1) In the `columns: [...]` definitions, you need to state where each column gets its data - for example `{ title: "Hospital", data: "hospital" },`, where that `hospital` label needs to be whatever you are using in your JSON. (2) There are various ways to format a column's data - for example, a [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) function: `"render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) { ... }`, where that `data` variable (each cell value) can be altered as needed.

Comment: (3) You can simplify some of the overall structure of your logic by using the DataTables ajax option, instead of using the jQuery ajax option. There are various examples [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/). This is not required, but I find the end result can be simpler.

Comment: @andrewjames is it right to have the DataTable code inside an ajax call?

Comment: I Agree with @andrewjames about using ajax provided by DT instead calling DT inside the ajax callback. Additionally if you have large data, you might consider using [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/) as it handle all DT actions (e.g. searching, sorting, paging) via ajax by itself. This way you can manipulate your data on the server side before it's rendered to JSON.

Comment: "_is it right to have the DataTable code inside an ajax call?_" - It's not wrong - you can absolutely do things that way if you prefer to or need to.

Comment: @andrewjames I have edited my question to reflect just DataTables server side processing.

Comment: Thank you for the updates. Can you show us the raw JSON text response? Since that is what's causing the error you report, we need to see what it looks like - its overall structure and some of the data records it contains.

Comment: @andrewjames: I've gotten my results to display (yay!) but not to sort the columns or to display n rows at a time, so I'm going to submit a different question.